# Timed Out Starting Mysqld Daemon when setting up replication

Tags: mysql, replication

I am now doing the MySQL Master Slave Replication between two of my fedora core 8 servers, on master every time I uncomment `log-bin=/var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin` and then try to restart the server, it shows the following error:

> Cannot Start Mysqld Service..Timed Out
>   Starting Mysqld Daemon

Comment: Check what is displayed in the mysqld log file - normally /var/log/mysqld.log

Answer (score 0):

Does the user mysql runs as (usually "mysql") have read-write access to the binary log?